# Emacs - setting comment character by file extension

Tags: emacs, comments

I work with a certain group of files (ASCII readable) but with weird extension names. The comment character in all of these is `#`

Everytime I comment lines, I have to set the comment character for every file-open-close cycle. Is there a way in which I can set up `.emacs` file to know which comment character to use ?

Comment: Doesn't get you all the way there, but you could put `-*- comment-start: "#"; -*-` at the top of each file, that way you only have to set it once per file.

Comment: What mode do these files come up in?

Comment: The files come up in "fundamental" mode

Answer (score 7):

Do all the files live within a common directory tree?

If so, then you could simply place a file named `.dir-locals.el` at the top level of that tree, with the contents:

```
((fundamental-mode . ((comment-start . "#"))))
```

For details, read:
<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs) Directory Variables` <kbd>RET</kbd>

(That approach has the bonus that anyone else using Emacs to access those files will also benefit from the `.dir-locals.el` file.)

Otherwise I'd be inclined to create a simple derived mode with that comment character, and assign all those file extensions to it. If you're dealing with these files in lots of different places, that would probably be the way to go:

```el
(define-derived-mode my-mode fundamental-mode "MyMode"
  "Comments start with `#'."
  (set (make-local-variable 'comment-start) "#"))

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.\(foo\|bar\)\\'" . my-mode))
```

That will make files with `.foo` and `.bar` extensions start in `my-mode` with the `#` comment character.

Comment: I had also to set `(set (make-local-variable 'comment-start-skip) "#")` for `M-x uncomment-region` to work. (Aquamacs 3.2 GNU Emacs 24.4.51.2)

Answer (score 6):

Put the following line somewhere in your init.el:

```
(setq-default comment-start "# ")
```

This will make "# " the default comment string in fundamental mode, which is a reasonable default anyway.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is evaluate `(setq comment-start "#")` every time in one of those buffers. This will ensure that when you run `(comment-region)` on a region, that it'll works, as well as with `(comment-dwim)`.

You could even bind a keybinding to that as a function for instance.

EDIT: After experimentation, I believe that after you evaluated it once in Emacs, it'll stay like that for fundamental mode. This should be very convenient, as you'll only have to evaluate it once.

Comment: The OP probably wants that in `fundamental-mode-hook`, right?

Comment: I tried that, but fundamental hook does not exist. Source: http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/elisp/elisp_21.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet of code, and adjust the variable to contain the pairs of regular expressions (matching file names (extensions)) and comment strings.  And, if you want to set `comment-end`, make the pairs triplets and adjust the function accordingly.

```
(defvar comment-based-on-extension-alist '((".el$" . "gg") (".txt$" . " >") (".odd$" . "$"))
  "alist of regexps and comment characters")

(defun setup-comment-based-on-extension ()
  (let ((alist comment-based-on-extension-alist))
    (while alist
      (when (string-match-p (caar alist) (buffer-file-name))
        (setq comment-start (cdar alist))
        (setq alist nil))
      (setq alist (cdr alist)))))
(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'setup-comment-based-on-extension)
```